# links in the margin of a centered image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is also a link using

```
<a href="link.html"><img src="img.png" id="cloud"></img></a>
```

And I centered it (and resized it) using

```
 #cloud
{
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:45%;
}
```

The problem is, the clickable area for the link extends across the entire web page, rather than just across the image. How would I fix this?

Comment: It looks like your CSS is calling on the id "#cloud" not "#centerimage". Could that be the issue?

Comment: Could you provide a little more HTML and CSS please? This sounds quite simple. But as @badAdviceGuy said, you aren't even targeting the same `ID`.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy that was probably a mistake when posting, because otherwise the image wouldn't have gotten the full width in the first place.

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean his point wasn't correct, that the `id` ref in the `html` is different than the `css`.

Comment: Sorry, that was the actual ID. I just changed the images and ids to generic names for simplicity

Comment: Can you just make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and I'll fix this in about 30 seconds.

Comment: Can I assume you're dealing with [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/3TbVv/)??

Comment: @NicholasHazel probably just with http://jsfiddle.net/3TbVv/1/

Comment: Joeytje50's link is exactly my problem

Comment: I believe I solved it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could always use `absolute positioning`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="link.html" >
    <img id="centerimage" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg" />
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#centerimage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

- **JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/3TbVv/3/

---

If you needed to place the element within the range of your **document structure**, you could apply a `wrapper` with a `CSS` class of `relative`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="link.html" >
        <img id="centerimage" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#centerimage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

- **JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/3TbVv/4/

---

**Expansion:** The reason why it was showing your link across the entire page is because you were using `display:block;` and there was no `wrapper` or any sort of containment for it. `display:block;` is inherently a `100%` width element.

Furthermore, `display:inline;` wouldn't have worked either, as it would fix the problem, but just adjust it to the left edge of the screen. If it doesn't have a `100%` width to go off of, it can't set `margins`.

Easiest solution would be to just `wrapper` it in, and style *the wrapper* element while you set some sort of `absolute position` with your `img`. That will ensure it will stay within the `wrapper`, and you can position the `wrapper` accordingly in your `document` by normal means, hence the `relative` style.

Comment: Read up if you'd like to on why yours didn't work. (added expansion)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work but try doing

```
<img src="img.png" id="centerimage" href = "link.html"/>
```

if this does not work try useing javascript or jquery

```
<img src="img.png" id="centerimage" onClick = "click" href = "link.html"/>

<script>

function click() {
window.location.href = "link.html";
}

</script>
```

then add this to the css

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: I'd prefer to try this without Javascript, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. If nobody else comes up with a solution I'll try it though. Thanks.

Edit: Javascript didn't work.

Comment: I don't recall seeing `javascript` added as a tag.

Comment: ik I got banned from questions so :( @NicholasHazel

Comment: How so...? Banned from commenting or asking questions?

Comment: asking questions :( @NicholasHazel but I don't blame them, looking back my questions are really stupid

Comment: Well, start answering some :-) That'll get your rep up. I've asked some pretty dumb questions myself.